# Tableview, selected cells, not accepting user clicks

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a uitableview that is like a preferences page. I save user selections using NSDefaults, and on load I reload those defaults and setup the tableview cells to appear selected.

I do this in this method

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//if this cell should look as if it was selected as a preference {
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.selected = true;
}
else{
    cell.selected = false;
}
return cell;
}
```

Now if the user unselects a cell I handle that here

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

the problem I have is that if I load the app, and then set my cells properly that were previously selected, they never accept a click event on them!! so the user can never unselect them.

Comment: can u make ur question more precise

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully its clearer.

Comment: try this method funkycoldmedid    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexpath.row == selectedrow) {
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.selected = true;
}
else{
    cell.selected = false;cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
}
return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful to you .

try this method

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexpath.row == selectedrow) {
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(200/255.0) green:(200/255.0) blue:(200/255.0) alpha:0.6];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;
    cell.selected = true;
}
else{
    cell.selected = false;cell.selectedBackgroundView = nil;
}
return cell;
}
```

Please let me know if you need any details .

Comment: I think you are not clearing the NSUserDefaults in the didselectrowatindexpath method . Please go through this example https://github.com/cwalcott/UITableView-Tutorial

Comment: Please let me know if there are any issues

Comment: I am clearing NSUserDefaults properly, still not affecting this.

Comment: hmmm Can you Please go through this code https://github.com/cwalcott/UITableView-Tutorial